# Importing a function from another directory within a package

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I am working with the following directory in Python3.8:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    /folder1
       __init__.py
       file1.py
       /folder2
          __init__.py
          file2.py
    /folder3
       __init__.py
       file3.py
```

I would like to import a function from file3 into file2. What is the easiest way to do it? I would also like to avoid manually appending to PYTHONPATH, to make this as smooth as possible for the next person pulling the project.

So far tried relative imports, which didn't work, possibly because I did not specify something in the init, which is currently empty. The error I am getting using:

```
from ..package.folder3.file3 import function_name
```

is

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is pretty simple, you need to add your `package` path to the system path.

Here is a complete example:

- In `file3.py`, let's create a simple function

  ```py
  def func():
      print("Hello from file3")
  ```
- In `file2.py`, we can import `func` function like so:

  ```py
  import os
  import sys
  sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../../..'))

  # import func now from file3
  from package.folder3.file3 import func

  func() #should return "Hello from file3"
  ```

Hopefully, this answers your question!

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Would it be possible to include the path from the __init__.py file in folder 2, so that it's appended for each script within folder2? Asking because it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your question. What do you mean by *"path from `init.py`"*? Also *"It's appended"*... appended to what?

Comment: In simpler terms, would it be possible to just run ```sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(...))```, or equivalent, from within __init__.py in folder2, instead of adding it in every file within folder2?

Comment: I don't think so... because the scope of this appended path is limited to the current script and doesn't extend to other scripts.